# How to get the probability of predict result in classification in tensorflow estimator.py?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am using the tensorflow to predict ctr of ads with the [google wide&deep model](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/wide_and_deep).
Absolutely, this is a classification problem which to predict the ad will be click(1) or not(0).

But the result of 1 or 0 should be computed with a probability such as if p(x=1) >0.2, the result will be 1, and otherwise 0.

My question is how to get the probability.

I have print much information in estimator.py[both use wide_n_deep model or wide model only], function predict and some functions it called in estimator.py or graph_actions.py.

But it doesn't work.(The predict result is also 0 or 1, not the probability of 0 or 1.)

In API DOCS, a method named predict_proba will return the probability. But when I use it as `pred_proba = m.predict_proba(x=None, input_fn=lambda: input_fn(df_test))`, it returns an array with infinite length. How to use this method?

My code was modified based on: [wide_n_deep_tutorial.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/learn/wide_n_deep_tutorial.py)

Thanks.

Comment: how it doesn't work, would you please specify more detail?

Comment: The predict result is also 0 or 1, not the probability of 0 or 1.

Comment: You may check the evaluate method which returning several metrics contain probability.

Comment: sorry, but I found the evaluate method returns the accuracy, auc and so on. But not the probability. Could you tell more detailed? and in the API, a method named predict_prob is said to generate the probality, but when i use it, it return an array with infinite length.

Comment: what's your version of tensorflow?

Comment: >>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> tf.__version__
'0.12.1'

Answer (score 0):

Replace the 
`pred_proba = m.predict_proba(x=None, input_fn=lambda: input_fn(df_test))`

By
`pred_proba = m.predict_proba(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(df_test))`